# Cordova InAppBrowser.open. Links are opening on safari instead of opening inside the app

Tags: android, ios, cordova, inappbrowser

My small cordova app is quite simple and, after checking that there's a connection, opens the url of a website (ex. http://www.example.com).
I want that all the urls/websites are showed within the app.

The main problem is that on iOS opens only the first page in the app and any other link that is clicked/touched opens in the safari browser.

in the config.xml
I already set

```
<access origin="*" />
```

while in the index.js I added

```
  onDeviceReady: function() {
        window.open = cordova.InAppBrowser.open;
        if (navigator.connection.type == Connection.NONE) {
      navigator.notification.alert('An internet connection is required to continue');
      } else {
          setTimeout(function(){window.open('http://www.example.com', '_self', 'location=no')} , 3000);

      }
    },
```

I already tried to use my code without inappbrowser (without the second line in the previous code and without the plugin).
I already removed and readded the platforms.
I recreated the whole application.
I checked the app (cordova platform check).

On anrdoid and blackberry it works as I need it with the navigation inside the app (with and without inappbrowser)!

cordova 6.1.1
mac mini - osx el capitan 10.11.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believed this is caused by not properly setting the allow-intent href properties in the config.xml as outlined here:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-10859

In your config.xml file look for this declaration:

`<allow-intent href="*" />`

And replace it with with more specific intent allowances like:

```
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
```

That should cover most intents.

Comment: I added the specific website/url to the intent and added more permissions.
Everything after rebuilding the project from scracth and by copying the files from the older project.

It worked after a bit of time invested in it :). Thanks

Comment: Hi, I'm having the same issue. Would you mind sharing what you changed? Maybe post parts from your config.xml. Much appreciated!

Comment: @RaziSyed what I've posted above is exactly what is in my config file.